# Lost all power in bike

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, suzuki

I got a 98 katana gsxf750, I was riding back from work and on my way home, all the power to my dash, lights, and buttons cut out and won’t come back. I’ve checked all the fuses, the battery is charged, I’ve looked for loose wires and can’t find any. My parking lights turn on when I turn the key to that setting. But when I turn the key to power the bike, I still get no power to the gauge cluster, lights, or buttons. Any ideas?